# Python Code using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help with my code
I am trying to make a window that displays a number constantly going up by one.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set('hello')

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

x=0
num=x

while(x<10):
    sleep(2)
    var.set(str(x))
    x=x+1
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not use `sleep`, must be use `after(period in ms, callback)`

```
from tkinter import *

def update_number():
    global x
    x += 1
    var.set(str(x))
    root.after(1000, update_number)

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
x = 0
var.set('hello')
l = Label(root, textvariable=var)
l.pack()
root.after(1000, update_number)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: you can also use `var = IntVar(value=0)` instead of `x = 0` and then `var.set(var.get()+1)` without `global x`